# Dynamic path to Google Drive folder

Tags: excel, vba

A team has one xlsm file with the graphs and Update button within. As soon as the team member clicks update, the ppt opens with the table and graph embedded. 
There are two problems: (1) files should reside on Google Drive - the path to the Desktop Google Drive folder is different from a user to user; (2) different users will use different machines - Windows or Mac, thus, backslashes will change. 
When I realized that people won't go to macro to change the path, I added one line in xls itself - 'Insert the path to ppt' and the team member, in theory, should just paste the path to his Google Drive, run the macro, save ppt and it will be saved on the cloud automatically - see the line MyPath. Sweet? But I got feedback that it is too complex. Can you think of any way that allows xlsm to trigger ppt. uploaded on Google Drive?

I tried with the path in the macro itself; then, var definition in the xls itself.

````
'The script copy/pastes the table from the pg_3 sheet to ppt
    Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application, PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation, PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

    Sheets("pg_3").Activate
    MyPath = Range("G1")
    Set PPApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set PPPres = PPApp.Presentations.Open(MyPath)
    PPApp.Visible = True
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(5)

    'Copying/Pasting the group of a chart & text
    Set CostDetails = ActiveSheet.Range("B13:C25")
    CostDetails.Copy
    PPSlide.Select
    Set PPTable = PPSlide.Shapes.Paste
    With PPTable
        .Left = 250
        .Top = 5
        '.Width = 471.2827
        .Height = 10
    End With

    'Copying/Pasting the group of a chart & text
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 1")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Set PPShape = PPPres.Slides(5).Shapes.Paste
    With PPShape
        .Top = 300
        .Height = 200
        .Left = 600
        .Width = 350
    End With

End Sub```
````

Comment: `I added one line in xls itself - 'Insert the path to ppt' and the team member, in theory, should just paste the path to his Google Drive` for a normal user, yes that can be complex. Two option that I can think of... **1.** Use a folder browser. So that user can select the folder rather than typing the path. **2.** Instead of saving to the local folder, directly upload it to google drive?

Comment: You may want to see [THIS](http://www.excelgaard.dk/Lib/GetSpecialFolder/)

Comment: Ok I tested it, you can download a sample file from that site from `http://www.excelgaard.dk/Files/Workbooks/UDFs/GetSpecialFolder.XLSm`

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I cannot make heads or tail. I cannot figure out what the script should be. Assume that my ppt is located in the https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1Fz45TGEh23Gk-hxSn0wk5Fgo9uvXHU6/sth.ppt. Fist question, I need to change FileCopy to something like FileOpen. Then, how and where do I specify the exact folder as GetSpecialFolder(vbDirGoogleDrive) seems is intended to lead you to the Google Drive temp home.

Comment: Yes I agree it is slightly complicated. f I try to explain it, it will take hell lot of time and this also is not a place... What i recommend if download the Excel file and then In the Add-In see the Button which gives you the path. Simply see the code and backtrack. Delete what you do not need and make it compact for your application :) Otherwise, the simplest solution is to ask the user to select the folder in few clicks...

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I am actually surprised that there are no link about this use case of opening the file at Google Drive on the Internet. Thank you for the resource. Let me dig into it.